# Were women not allowed to honour their ancestors?

Tags: culture

祭祖的时候，贾敬是主祭，贾赦是陪祭，贾珍献爵，贾琏贾琮献帛，宝玉捧香。青衣奏乐，献爵三次，焚帛奠酒。

As far as I know, 贾敬、贾赦、贾珍、贾琏、贾琮、宝玉都是男人。

青衣，I'm not sure if this is a woman or a man.

没有什么贾氏的女人。

Were women not allowed to make offerings to their ancestors?

Answer (score 1):

> [女人在古代能不能进祠堂？](https://zhidao.baidu.com/question/185599929.html)

Base on this post, women were not even normally allowed to enter the 宗祠 (ancestors' hall). let alone hosting a rite there in olden time China.

But it only happened in 父系社會 (Patriarchal society). We all know before the patriarchal society time, China was a 母系社會 (Matriarchal society). I am sure the jobs of 祭司 (priest) would be held by women back then.

> *https://kknews.cc/culture/28llalz.html*
>
> *在封建社會裡，大戶人家在每年的"祭宗祠″和死了人出殯時，都要請這些走出門戶便叫作"青衣″的人來演奏一番"祭祀″的音樂。*

青衣 seems to referring to 'musician'

Comment: In ancient China, color of clothing could signify the rank and status of wearer's, and 青衣 was considered as the lowest. Therefore people with "inferior occupations" (such as 伎乐) were sometimes referred as 青衣.